# Can't change colour of lines on graph: JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Ok so I have a project for work which aims to provide an application to display response time/call volumes for online server. I have all of the backend complete where I retrieve/format stats to feed into graphs.

I am stuck on **changing the color of the lines!*, which is strange because line colours are automatically different in this exmaple: [JFreeChart example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartOverlaidBarChartDemo.htm). Find the source code for my graph creation class below. Any help would be much, much appreciated (I am working on this on a Sunday as I did not want it to run into the New Year!!)

Source code: [JFreeChart forum post by myself](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116765) -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the problem is caused by one renderer being used for multiple datasets (where each dataset has only one series).  In that case, whatever colour you specify in the renderer will apply to all the series across all the datasets.